# jQuery calculation doesn't add up as expected when toggling height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function for calculating the height of `.node`. It then takes away the height of a possible image, `.node-image`, from the height of the `.node`, and sets a column, `.node-content-column` to have a height that is the difference (i.e. 500 - 50 = 450; column becomes 450 in height).

```
function initColumnSizer() {
  imageHeight  = $('.node-image').outerHeight(true);
  resizeHeight = ($('.node').outerHeight() + 75) - imageHeight;
  $('.node-content-column').removeAttr('style');
  $('.node-content-column').css('min-height', resizeHeight);
  $('.node-content-column').css('height', 'auto !important');
  $('.node-content-column').css('height', resizeHeight);
}
```

This function gets called on page load, and resizes `.node-content-column` as expected.

It also gets called when a div within `.node` is toggled using `jQuery.toggle()`, but this calculation returns a larger number everytime, instead of reverting back to the original once this toggle is reverted.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong with this calculation? Or if I am going about it the wrong way?

Thanks in advance!
Karl

Comment: Can you post your outerHeight() method?

Comment: [outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) is a jQuery method

Comment: Just a note, you should cache your selector so it doesn't have to run several times. Eg. `var $column = $('.node-content-column');` then `$column.removeAttr('style'); $column.css('min-height', resizeHeight);` etc.

Comment: Good advice Drackir, I usually do this after I have gotten the code to work and more often earlier if it's a busier/bigger piece of functionality!

Answer (score 0):

1) Maybe the problem is in outerHeight() function (it takes into account padding and border). Try using just `height or clientHeight:`

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

2) why do you need to cleanup the whole elements' style? 
and then you try to assign `height = auto`, and after that: `height =  resizeHeight` - what's the purpose for that ? check the logic of your code.

Comment: The clearing was a bit of debug to see if the height was being re-added. The multiple height declarations are CSS cross-browser styles that ensure there will be a minimum height in all major browsers, but still allow it to scale.

Answer (score 0):

[outerHeight(true)](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) will return `height + padding + border + margin`. Possibly, you might want to use [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) ?

Comment: I need padding, margin and border

Answer (score 0):

Most possible is that "larger number everytime" have always constant difference -- for example 75.
May be you just have some dependecies between .node-content-column and .node?

---

If your nodes like .node-content-column, .node and .node-image are all singles, then it's better to use IDs for them -- not CSS classes.